# Как получить данные с сайта Пятерочка

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер

Как из ответа сервиса

```
r = requests.get('https://5ka.ru/api/stores/?bbox=10.0000,10.0000,100.0000,100.0000')
```

вытащить `"coordinates"` и `"address"`.

Пример возвращаемых данных (переносы строк и отступы добавлены для удобства, вообще сервис возвращает все в одну строку):

```
callback({
    "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        51.84103119,
                        55.12792649
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "city_id": 2471,
                    "work_start_time": "09:00:00",
                    "work_end_time": "23:00:00",
                    "is_24h": false,
                    "address": "Волгоградская ул., 32"
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": 9745,
                "options": {
                    "preset": "store.active"
                }
     ...
});
```

Comment: Приведите пример возвращаемых данных

Comment: @insolor {
    "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        51.84103119,
                        55.12792649
                    ]

Comment: Добавьте информацию в сам вопрос, для этого нажмите на ссылку "править" под ним.

Comment: @insolor добавил

Comment: А `callback(` в начале и `);` в конце не потеряли? Сервис возвращает не чистый json, а обернутый как бы в вызов функции.

Comment: @insolor нет не потерял можете сами проверить

Comment: Проверяю, `print(r.text[:100])` выводит `callback({"data":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[`

Comment: @ insolor странно

Comment: И у меня тоже: `callback({"data":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://5ka.ru/api/stores/?bbox=10.0000,10.0000,100.0000,100.0000')
if r.status_code == 200:
    j = json.loads(r.text[9:-2]) # обрезаем лишнее обрамление у JSON
    for feature in j['data']['features']:
        print('Координаты:', feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        print('Адрес:', feature['properties']['address'])
else:
    print('Ошибка получения данных, HTTP статус', r.status_code)
```

Вывод:

```
Координаты: [51.84103119, 55.12792649]
Адрес: Волгоградская ул., 32
Координаты: [68.99604356, 33.0824978]
Адрес: ул. Александрова, 20
Координаты: [61.3154729, 47.17058947]
Адрес: ул. Пушкина, 4
Координаты: [51.77765944, 55.10483466]
Адрес: ул. Терешковой, 10
...
```

Но грузит `JSON` довольно долго. И это очень `ad-hoc` решение.

P.S. Получить `JSON` средствами самого `request` через `r.json()` в данном случае не удаётся - в ответе не чистый `JSON`, а `HTML` с таким содержанием:

```
callback({"data":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":...});
```

Comment: Там список features, в каждом элементе свои координаты и адреса. Вы берете координаты от первого магазина, а адрес из второго) Нужно циклом по features пройти и вывести все.

Comment: @insolor Я просто показал примеры как можно вытащить конкретные поля. Что именно хочет автор вопроса - я лично не очень понял. И кто знает, какая там вообще структура информации, думаю, там не только эти поля надо смотреть )  Так то вы правы, конечно, но, думаю, автору вопроса этого кода должно быть достаточно, чтобы понять, что дальше делать в его случае.

Comment: Трудно сказать - достаточно, или он наоборот запутается) Я бы все-таки дополнил вопрос с выводом всего списка. Я начинал писать ответ, но вы опередили)

Comment: @insolor Придётся обрабатывать случаи, когда есть одно и нет другого, блин )

Comment: @insolor Хотя вроде всё есть, я просто слепой. Поменял код )

Comment: А зачем лишнее убирать из json? У requests есть метод для получения json: `j = r.json()`

Comment: @gil9red, потому что там не чистый json приходит, а строка, в которой json обернут в  `callback(...);`. Если просто метод `json()` вызвать, то выкинет ошибку.

Comment: @insolor, понятно... в вопросе об этом не было сказано )

Comment: @gil9red Почитайте комментарии к вопросу )  Я конечно пробовал `r.json()`, он ругается )  Добавил пояснение в ответ

Comment: @gil9red, поправил пример возвращаемых данных в вопросе, справедливость восстановлена)

Comment: @insolor, спасибо :)

Comment: @CrazyElf да код оч помог единственное почему то у меня выгружает только 1035 обьектов расположенные в конце а должно 16000

Comment: @Grechkin26 Не знаю, у меня перебирает 16302 элементов, наверное вы их как-то криво выгружаете.

Comment: @Grechkin26 Там правда много кривых адресов типа: Адрес: 19, Адрес: ТБО, Адрес: д. 43

Comment: @CrazyElf странно я использовал ваш пример

Comment: @CrazyElf кажется проблема в настройках VSC теперь все выгружает